# Normal to a parameterized surface- Can't prove

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given a surface $ F: D \in R^2\longrightarrow S \in R^3 $ with smooth parameteric representation:
$F(u,v) = (x(u,v),y(u,v), z(u,v)) $ .

Denote by $N = F_u \times  F_v $ , how can one prove that $N$  at  $p$  is orthogonal to any curve which lies in the surface and passes through  p?

I never saw such a proof, and I can't find it in Calculus books... (it bother me because always people refer to $N$ as the normal, but never saw such a proof)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\gamma : I \to S$ be such a curve, so that $\gamma(t) = F(u(t),v(t))$ for some functions $(u,v) : I \to D$. Then $\gamma'(t) = F_u u'(t) + F_v v'(t)$ by the chain rule. Since $N$ is orthogonal to $F_u$ and $F_v$, it is orthogonal to everything in their span, and in particular to $\gamma'(t)$.

Comment: I think what the OP needs in fact is the following easy theorem in three-dimensional analytic geometry: a straight line $\;l\;$ intersecting a plane $\;\pi\;$ is perpendicular to it (i.e., $\;l\perp\pi\;$) iff $\;l\;$ is perpendicular to  two straight lines contained in $\;\pi\;$ passing through the line's foot at $\;\pi\;$ , with foot = the intersection point of $\;l\,,\,\pi\;$  . With this we're done since $\;N\perp F_u\;,\;N\perp F_v\;$ .

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot ! A couple of questions, if I may:

1. Why does if $\gamma$ lies on our surface, then $\gamma(t)=F(u(t),v(t)) $ for some functions $u,v$? 

2. I'm a little confused about the notations-
$\gamma ' (t)$ is the tangent vector to $\gamma(t)$ .. But, since $\gamma(t)$ is a path, $\gamma'(t) $ must also be a path.. Why are we looking at it as a vector?

Thanks !

Comment: @homogenity: 1) By definition, the surface is the image of $F$, so every point $\gamma(t) \in S$ is of the form $F(u(t),v(t))$, for some $(u(t),v(t)) \in D$, and taking all of the values of $t$ together, we may view these $u(t)$ and $v(t)$ as functions on $I$ in their own. 2) Right, $\gamma'(t)$ you could view as a $t$-dependent path of tangent vectors; we're only really interested in $\gamma'(t)$ at the value of $t$ for which $\gamma(t) = p$.

Comment: Great !!! Thanks !